# Go: Unable to unmarshal json value

Tags: postgresql, go, jsonb

I have `jsonb` value stored in postgres columns which I need to convert to `object` to send the response

I am unable to convert JSON -> struct using `json.Unmarshal` method

```golang
type Result struct {
    Id          int 
    Expertise   string // because json string 
    Languages   string // because json string 
}

// saving dd query data to result struct 
e, _ := json.Marshal(data.Expertise)
l, _ := json.Marshal(data.Languages)
    row := r.db.QueryRow(`
        INSERT INTO filters (user_id, expertise, languages)
        VALUES ($1, $2, $3)
        ON CONFLICT (user_id) DO 
        UPDATE SET expertise=$2, languages=$3
        RETURNING id, expertise, languages;
    `, userid, e, l)

    var res Result 
    err := row.Scan(&res.Id, &res.Expertise, &res.Languages)
```

**Then I take this the Expertise and Languages field and UNMARSHAL THEM**

```golang
// helper method 
func Unmarshal(value string) interface{} {
    var obj interface{}
    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(value), &obj)
    return obj
}

type CreateFilterResponse struct {
    Id        int           `json:"id"`
    Expertise interface{}   `json:"expertise"`
    Languages interface{}   `json:"languages"`
}

response := dto.CreateFilterResponse{
        Id: res.Id,
        Expertise: Unmarshal(res.Expertise), //  not decoding, still json
        Languages: Unmarshal(res.Languages), //  not decoding, still json
}
```

I would really appreciate the help, I need the `Expertise` and `Languages` to be {} and [] respectively

This is what I am getting in response:

```
{"id":5,"expertise":"[{\"role\":1,\"experience\":5},
{\"role\":3,\"experience\":4}]","languages":"[1,2,3]"}
```

#### Note:

- Expertise is jsonb column : []{role: int, experience: int}
- Languages is jsonb column : []int

Comment: are `expertise` and `languages` columns both `jsonb`? maybe edit your question with the definition of the table `filters` to avoid confusion

Comment: yes, added. Both are jsonb columns

Comment: and what is the type of `e` and `l` in your `QueryRow`? Still `string` like the fields in `Result` struct?

Comment: no, they are marshalled values of objects `e, _ := json.Marshal(data.Expertise)` 
`l, _ := json.Marshal(data.Languages)`. Updated the code as well

Comment: I believe the issue is that you are scanning the jsonb bytes into `string`, which causes it to be interpreted literally. Then when you pass a string into `json.Unmarshal` it stays a string. Change the type of `Expertise` and `Language` to `[]byte` (or `json.RawMessage`)

Comment: Hey, thanks man, I took your suggestion and it worked. Ive posted an answer, could you review the last part?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Blackgreen comment, the suggestion worked.

As he suggested "I believe the issue is that you are scanning the jsonb bytes into string, which causes it to be interpreted literally. Then when you pass a string into json.Unmarshal it stays a string. Change the type of Expertise and Language to []byte (or json.RawMessage)"

I did the same and it works, here is the code:

```
// for parsing jsonb coming from db query
type Result struct {
    Id          int 
    Expertise   json.RawMessage // change
    Languages   json.RawMessage // change 
}

// the database query itself 
e, _ := json.Marshal(filters.Expertise)
l, _ := json.Marshal(filters.Languages)

row := r.db.QueryRow(`
        INSERT INTO filters (user_id, expertise, languages)
        VALUES ($1, $2, $3)
        ON CONFLICT (user_id) DO 
        UPDATE SET expertise=$2, languages=$3
        RETURNING id, expertise, languages;
    `, userid, e, l)

var res Result 
err := row.Scan(&res.Id, &res.Expertise, &res.Languages) // scanning to result
if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Unable to create a new filter ==>", err)
        return nil, err
}
```

Then I `Unmarshalled` the `expertise` and `languages` jsonb values using a helper method and created a `Response` struct for the client:

```
// response struct type 
type CreateFilterResponse struct {
    Id          int         `json:"id"`
    Expertise   interface{} `json:"expertise"`
    Languages   interface{} `json:"languages"`
}

// final response struct 
response := dto.CreateFilterResponse{
    Id: res.Id,
    Expertise: Unmarshal(res.Expertise),
    Languages: Unmarshal(res.Languages),
}   

// helper method 
func Unmarshal(value []byte) interface{} {
    var obj interface{}
    json.Unmarshal(value, &obj)
    return obj
}
```

This works for now. *I still need to find an easy way to do this as this is too much boilerplate code to perform a simple task.* **like in JS/TS it can be done using single line of code** `JSON.parse(value)`

Comment: Is the client to which you send the `CreateFilterResponse` response a client that expects a JSON response? If so then why don't you use `Result` directly? The whole `response := CreateFilterResponse{ ...` step seems redundant.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is in the json output. It is encoding your JSON twice, making it difficult to read and deserialize the json in your structure.

You can start by organizing your structures as follows:

```
type Expertise struct {
    Role       int `json:"role"`
    Experience int `json:"Experience"`
}

type CreateFilterResponse struct {
    Id        int         `json:"id"`
    Expert    []Expertise `json:"expertise"`
    Languages []int       `json:"languages"`
}
```

I made a cleaner method just to exemplify and facilitate understanding. It will remove the unnecessary quotes and escapes so you can convert your string to []bytes and unmarshal your structure.

```
func jsonCleaner(quoted string) []byte{
    quoted = strings.ReplaceAll(quoted, "\n", "")
    quoted = strings.ReplaceAll(quoted, "\\", "")
    quoted = strings.ReplaceAll(quoted, "]\"", "]")
    quoted = strings.ReplaceAll(quoted, "\"[", "[")
    dataBytes := []byte(quoted)
    fmt.Println(dataBytes)
    return dataBytes
}
```

**Your json message would go from:**

```
{"id":5,"expertise":"[{\"role\":1,\"experience\":5},{\"role\":3,\"experience\":4}]","languages":"[1,2,3]"}
```

**To:**

```
{"id":5,"expertise":[{"role":1,"experience":5},"role":3,"experience":4}],"languages":[1,2,3]}
```

Comment: Idk how ideal this solution is, but this seems to do the job. Still it feels like a hack

Comment: Help me understand something. in that line

err := row.Scan(&res.Id, &res.Expertise, &res.Languages)

Does the method already take the JSON data to the struct?
If so, I believe the cleaning method is unnecessary. Would it just be necessary to adjust the structures?